# Haskell check if two varaints (and not the corresponding values) of a sum data type are the same

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

How can I check if **two variants of a sum data type** are **the same**? I can't just derive `Eq` because that would compare the elements inside, too.

The obvious way to do this is to write a pattern match for every single variant, for example:

```hs
data Token = Ident String | Number String | Let | Dec

myeq (Ident _) (Ident _) = True
myeq (Number _) (Number _) = True
myeq Let Let = True
myeq Dec Dec = True
myeq _ _ = False
```

However, **my actual `Token` type is much longer than this**, so this would be **tedious**. Is there a better way to do this? Coming from rust, is there something like [`std::mem::discriminant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html)?

Note:
The behaviour I'm looking for is `Ident "foo" == Ident "bar"` to be `True`. Note how the strings in the `Ident` aren't the same. BTW, I need this because I'm writing a parser that takes in a list of tokens, and need to match the type of token but not the contents of the token.

Comment: Look up `deriving` expressions: `data Token = Ident String | Number String | Let | Dec deriving (Eq)`. (Not writing this as an answer as I strongly suspect this to be a duplicate question, though I’m not quite sure what it’s a duplicate of.)

Comment: As I stated in the question, that's (sadly) not what I'm looking for. If I derive `Eq`, then the `String` fields in the `Token` datatype would be compared, which I don't want.

Deriving would result in `Ident "foo" == Ident "bar"` to be `True` when I want it to be `False`.

I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for clarifying! Evidently I missed that part of the question. Unfortunately, I know of no easy way to automatically write such functions. Furthermore, I strongly recommend not writing such an `Eq` instance: there is a [convention](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq) that ‘two values comparing equal are indistinguishable by "public" functions’, which your instance would violate.

Comment: Oh ok. Either way, the question still stands: how can I have this behaviour? (doesn't have to be the implementation for `Eq`, but as an external function).

Comment: As I said, I know of no easy ways to do this. Of the non-easy ways, you might want to look into generics or Template Haskell, though these are complicated and you may not want to use them for your specific usecase.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that link you sent! I'm not sure how I didn't see it. This seems to be a duplicate then.